# htaccess restrict access to index.php only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, webserver, http-status-code-403

I was writing a `.htaccess` file for my PHP script.
This should only allow access to the `index.php`, `cronjob.php` and `execute.php` pages.
I wrote the `.htaccess` file as follows:

```xml
# Set default index file
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Disable indexing
Options -Indexes

# Set "403 Forbidden" as the default server behavior
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

# Allow requests to core PHP files
<FilesMatch "(index|execute|cronjob)\.php$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

# If mod_rewrite module exists...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # ...restrict access to PHP private directories
    RewriteRule (^|/)logs(/|$) - [F]
    RewriteRule (^|/)utils(/|$) - [F]
    RewriteRule (^|/)modules(/|$) - [F]
</IfModule>
```

---

The main problem with this code is that `https://example.com/` returns `403 Forbidden`,
while `https://example.com/index.php` works.

Answer (score 1):

You could put condition to check if a URI is NOT having either `index.php` OR `cronjob.php` or `execute.php` then forbid that page so else other pages will be forbid apart from these 3 php uris.

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before checking your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index|cronjob|execute)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to get it to work, I don't know if it's the best `.htaccess` possible, but this is what I ended up with:

```xml
# Set default index file
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Disable indexing
Options -Indexes

# Set "403 Forbidden" as the default server behavior
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

# Allow requests to core PHP files
<FilesMatch "^((index|execute|cronjob)\.php)?$">  # Basically, it accepts the three PHP files and the empty string.
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for sharing, so my answer didn't help you? I tested it and it worked fine, could you please do let me know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, it does. I read it after writing mine. Thanks anyway.